# Integration between our Asp.NET MVC form authentication and Office 365

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, office365, exchange-server

I have the following:-

1) Intranet Asp.net MVC-4 web application, which currently authenticate the users using form authentication with our on-premises active directory through ldap string.

2) So users enter their username and password >> the application will authenticate their user names and passwords from AD and login them accordingly.

3) Now our organization will turn off the on-pressies AD, and we will migrate to office 365.

so i am not sure if i can modify my asp.net mvc-4 intranet (access from our internal network only) to authenticate the entered username and password from office 365 instead of using ldap string?

currently the login is been performed as follow:-

the login post action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{  
    MembershipProvider domainProvider;
    domainProvider = Membership.Providers["Domain1ADMembershipProvider"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        // Validate the user with the membership system.
        if (domainProvider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {               
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            List<String> domains2 = new List<String>();
            domains2.Add("AD-*****GROUP");
            ViewBag.Domains = domains2;
            return View(model);
        }

    }
    List<String> domains = new List<String>();
    domains.Add("AD-*********GROUP");
    ViewBag.Domains = domains;
    return View(model);
}
```

web.config contain the ldap to the on-premises AD and username/password settings:-

```
 <membership>
      <providers>
        <add name="Domain1ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="Domain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="********8" connectionPassword="********" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
      </providers>
   </membership>  
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Domain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ad-*****roup.intra/OU=TDM,DC=ad-***group,DC=intra" />
```

i do not have any idea from where to start and if i can achive what i am looking for,, and if this is supported or not?

Comment: Since this is intranet, you can use their domain account as the login.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @pcalkins this will not work in our case as we deploy our application on a different domain compare to the AD domian, i am asking about login within Office 365